# Delete unmanaged Databricks table data from SQL

Tags: databricks, delta-lake, databricks-sql

I have an unmanaged table in Databricks and I want to delete the underlying data when I drop the table.

I have checked this [link](https://medium.com/@harun.raseed093/managed-unmanaged-tables-in-databricks-aa630e5c1c10)

As per that, if I run the command

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS <example-table> 
dbutils.fs.rm("<your-storage-path>", true)
```

The drop table command works fine, but the dbutils fails with error below:

```
Error: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
mismatched input 'dbutils' expecting {'(', 'ADD', 'ALTER', 'ANALYZE', 'CACHE', 'CLEAR', 'COMMENT', 'COMMIT', 'CREATE', 'DELETE', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'DFS', 'DROP', 'EXPLAIN', 'EXPORT', 'FROM', 'GRANT', 'IMPORT', 'INSERT', 'LIST', 'LOAD', 'LOCK', 'MAP', 'MERGE', 'MSCK', 'REDUCE', 'REFRESH', 'REPLACE', 'RESET', 'REVOKE', 'ROLLBACK', 'SELECT', 'SET', 'SHOW', 'START', 'TABLE', 'TRUNCATE', 'UNCACHE', 'UNLOCK', 'UPDATE', 'USE', 'VALUES', 'WITH'}(line 1, pos 0)

== SQL ==
dbutils.fs.rm("gs://bambi-delta-test/tenants/7587/lsdata/schema_vk/dimproduct", True)
^^^
```

I am calling these SQL commands from a C# code, so cant use the Python or other librares.

Thanks for your help.
Vik

Comment: it seems you forgot to add an end of line symbol before `dbutils` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dbutils.fs.rm` is Scala/Python command, not the SQL command, so you can't combine it together.  Right now there is no commands for removal of the files in Databricks SQL, so you need to perform `DROP` via SQL, and then remove files using the Google Storage library for .Net